# Getting the attachment URL instead of the ID (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a script that allows me to upload an image to wordpress from the front end. I then need it to post the file to the post_meta. Right now it's working fine, BUT I end up with the Attachment ID and need the LINK to the file.

Here's the code that is handling this particular function.

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $k => $v) {
        if ($k != 'poster_has_paid' && $k != 'featured_image') {
            if ($_FILES[$k]) {
                wpo_poster_insert_attachment($k, $post_id, false, $k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the function wpo_poster_insert_attachment

```
function wpo_poster_insert_attachment($file_handler, $post_id, $setthumb = 'false', $post_meta = '') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        __return_false();
    }

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file_handler, $post_id);

    if ($setthumb) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    }
    if (!$setthumb && $post_meta != '') {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $post_meta, $attach_id);
    }

    return $attach_id;
```

Again, it's updating the field with the attach_id, and I'd like it to update the attach_url

PS I will give thanks when I have enough posts to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
function wpo_poster_insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false', $post_meta = '') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);

        // Get the attachment/thumbnail source, and add it to the post meta as well.
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, 'full');
        update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_src', @$src[0]);
    }

    if(!$setthumb && $post_meta!=''){
        update_post_meta($post_id, $post_meta, $attach_id);
    }

    return $attach_id;
}
```

But normally, since you already have the thumbnail_id stored in the post meta, you might want to pull the attachment source at run-time:

```
if($thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true)) {
    $attachment_size = 'full';
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, $attachment_size);
    if(!$src) {
            $src = array('http://mysite.com/path/to/default-image.png', 640, 480);
    }
    echo '<img src="'.esc_url($src[0]).'" alt="" />';
}
```